# load data of hover image

Tags: javascript, html, hover

First of all i'm new at scripting and need your help. I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have four projects i want to show on my website. These projects are visable by images. When people hover over the image a div called "info" will show the additional information of the project they hover on.

So to be clear, data which will be triggered by hovering goes to the same div "info":

Hover over image 1 -> load information of project 1 to -> div "info"

Hover over image 2 -> load information of project 2 to -> div "info"
etc.

A friend told me to use ajax and xml, is that a good combination?

Thanks for the help

Comment: put the info hidden on your site, on hover load the info in to the <div>

Answer (score 1):

You are right that a good way to load content dynamically on a page is to use Javascript and XML. A great way to get into using JavaScript is to load a library to help you operate on the contents of an HTML page. I definitely recommend JQuery.

I would highly recommend not loading the information from separate files, unless the content is a whole bunch of very large images.

Take look at this video: [JQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-look-tim-van-damme/) they do some really great videos that helped me understand JQuery when I was first starting. The page that I just linked to has some great techniques for switching content into the same place, and will give you some important UX (user experience) tips as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is the best choice to get the data....

But the variations comes at what type of Data...

> if you need values from database **JSON** would be my choice

or

- *never mind any data can be smoothly framed*

if you dont have too much hand on scripting

Just use Jquery Plugins to retrieve data using simple calls

> **[Fancybox plugin CLICK HERE...](http://fancybox.net/)**

and the GUIDE to how to use

> **[GUIDE TO USE FANCYBOX CLICK HERE.....](http://fancybox.net/howto)**

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for the response.

I solved the problem temporarily by using the technique given by Mark, using html and css. But, i think using javascript could make things easier and more organised. My knowledge about scripting is not good enough. I posted my html for others underneath.

I still have the question how to use the id of a image as a parameter for retrieving a specific part of information. For example: i have an image with id=img1 and a xml file containing  with sub parameters. So when i hover over the image js gets the id of that image and then loads the specific part of the xml onto the "info"div and not the whole xml. (to answer the question of adam, the data type is just text)

```
enter code here

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        div.maincontent{
            border: none;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }

        div.leftcol, div.rightcol {
            /*
             * Note that the left column and the right column use position fixed
             * to make placement of the elements on top easier.
             */
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            width:200px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
        }
        div.leftcol{
            left:0px;
        }
        div.rightcol{
            right:0px;
        }
        div.middlecontent{
            /*
             * Note the left and right margin to place the div. 
             * With this margin you can  
             */
            margin:0px 200px 0px 200px;
            position: absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;

        }
        div.square{
            float:left;
            margin:0px;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            border:10px solid black;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        div.left_content, .right_content {
            /*
             *Initially do not display the div.left_content
             *and div.right_content.
             *I still set the all the styles here the divs have in common.
             */ 
            margin:0px;
            position:fixed;
            margin:0px;
            top:0px;
            width:200px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
            color:white;
            display: none; /* do not display */
        }

        div.square:hover > div.left_content {
            /*
             *When you hover over a square take from the children
             *those with div.left_content and display them.
             *The left one is displayed on top of the left div.leftcol
             */ 
            left:0px;
            display:block;    
        }
        div.square:hover > div.right_content {
            /*
             *When you hover over a square take from the children
             *those with div.right_content and display them.
             *The right one is displayed on top of the right div.rightcol
             */ 

            right:0px;
            display:block;    
        }   
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="maincontent">
        <div class="leftcol">
            <p>
                Hover over the blue divs in the middle
            </p>
            <p>
                This trick uses the &gt; to find children of an element.
                The children are only displayed when hovering over the parent element.
                Look at the CSS how that is done. for instance for the left div it is
                div.square:hover &gt; div.left_content
            </p>
            <p> something inside the left column</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightcol">
            <p>something inside the right column</p>
        </div>

        <div class="middlecontent">
            <div class="square">
                <!--
                    this div has two children
                        a div with class="left_content" and
                        a div with class="right_content"

                -->
                <div class="left_content">
                    <p> first div </p>
                    <p> something as left content </p>
                </div>
                <div class="right_content">
                    <p> first div </p>
                    <p> something as right content </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="square">
                <div class="left_content">
                    <p> second div </p>
                    <p> something as left content </p>
                </div>
                <div class="right_content">
                    <p> second div </p>
                    <p> something as right content </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="square">
                <div class="left_content">
                    <p> third div </p>
                    <p> something as left content </p>
                </div>
                <div class="right_content">
                    <p> third div </p>
                    <p> something as right content </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```